# Can provider name in get_driver function of libcloud be sent as python input provider?

Tags: python-3.x, libcloud

I have multiple clouds and want to send the provider name as input parameter to the get_driver function in apache libcloud.

Comment: Are you wanting to send a provider name to your Python script as a parameter and you wanted that parameter to somehow be a valid `get_driver` parameter? If you can edit your question and add an example of what you are trying to do and where the issue is, we might be able to help.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your code?

Comment: This is my code.

provider = input("Who is the cloud provider?")

cls = get_driver(Provider.provider)

driver = cls('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',api_version='v2')
pprint(driver.list_nodes())

When I provide the input as DIGITAL_OCEAN.

I am getting an error 'AttributeError: Provider DIGITAL_OCEAN does not exist'